# Problema con imagen FullScreen en Mozilla

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Tengo mi función para agrandar una imagen a pantalla completa, lo cual me funciona en Google Chrome pero no en otros navegadores.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
$("#Button1").click(function (ev) {       
  launchFullScreen(document.getElementById('imagen_test'), 'imagen_test');
});

function launchFullScreen(element, id_imagen) {
  if (element.requestFullScreen) {
    element.requestFullScreen();
  } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {            
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) { 
    element.webkitRequestFullScreen();            
  }
  $('#' + id_imagen).addClass('aumenta_imagen');
}
```

```css
.aumenta_imagen{
  width:80% !important;
  max-width:none !important;
  height:100% !important;                
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="imagen_test" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/180/people" style="height:180px;width:100px;max-width:120px;" />
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
```

Pero cuando lo pruebo en Mozilla, para agrandar la imagen en pantalla completa, ocurre lo siguiente: Ocupa todo el ancho y alto, lo cual hace que la imagen se vea desproporcionada.

Me gustaría saber, ¿qué debo hacer para que también en Mozilla se vea bien la imagen en pantalla completa?

Comment: Esta pregunta necesita un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable (emcv)](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Es difícil visualizar el problema y un emcv sería perfecto en este caso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pude reproducir el problema. Ocurre porque Chrome, Firefox e IE/Edge interpretan la pantalla completa de manera diferente cuando se aplica a una imagen (aunque tengo que buscar fuentes que demuestren este punto):

- En Chrome, la imagen se agranda proporcionalmente hasta que llega a un tope (el alto o el ancho de la ventana).
- En Firefox e IE/Edge, la imagen se maximiza ocupando el 100% de la pantalla tanto en horizontal como en vertical (por lo que la imagen se ve estirada).

Chrome parece que respeta el CSS hasta cierto punto, mientras que Firefox e IE/Edge lo ignoran directamente y le aplica su propio estilo de imagen a pantalla completa.

Teniendo eso en cuenta, dejo aquí dos posibles soluciones (la segunda me gusta más porque me parece más limpia):

**Opción 1: Aplica la pantalla completa al body**

Podrías aplicar la pantalla completa al elemento `body` y entonces hacer que la imagen seleccionada tenga unos estilos diferentes. De esta manera evitas los posibles problemas con Firefox e IE. Casi mejor si también añades un *scrim* (un telón o capa intermedia más oscura para separar más visualmente la imagen del resto de contenido).

Por ejemplo, se podría hacer algo así:

```js
$("#Button1").click(function (ev) {       
  launchFullScreen(document.getElementById('body'), 'imagen_test');
});

function launchFullScreen(element, id_imagen) {
  if (element.requestFullScreen) {
    element.requestFullScreen();
  } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {            
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) { 
    element.webkitRequestFullScreen();            
  }
  $('#' + id_imagen).addClass('aumenta_imagen');
}
```

```css
.aumenta_imagen{
  height: 100% !important;
  width: auto !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 99999;               
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <img id="imagen_test" src="http://www.lorempixel.com/100/180/people" style="height:180px;width:100px;max-width:120px;" /> 
  <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
</body>
```

**Opción 2: Poner la imagen como fondo**

Si en lugar de poner la imagen como imagen (con una etiqueta `img`) se pone como fondo de un `div` (usando `background-image` y `background-size:contain`), al aplicar la pantalla completa, el `div` ocupa toda la ventana pero por el tamaño del fondo indicado, se muestra de manera correcta.

Éste sería un ejemplo del código:

```js
$("#Button1").click(function (ev) {       
  launchFullScreen(document.getElementById('imagen_test'), 'imagen_test');
});

function launchFullScreen(element, id_imagen) {
  if (element.requestFullScreen) {
    element.requestFullScreen();
  } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {            
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) { 
    element.webkitRequestFullScreen();            
  }
  $('#' + id_imagen).addClass('aumenta_imagen');
}
```

```css
#imagen_test {
  height:180px;
  width:100px;
  background-size:contain;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center center;
}

.aumenta_imagen {
  width:100% !important;
  height:100% !important;
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imagen_test" style="background-image:url(http://www.lorempixel.com/100/180/people);"></div>
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
```

Este segundo ejemplo no se ve bien porque el iframe en el que se ejecuta no permite pantalla completa. Copia el código a una página y ejecútalo de manera local para ver los resultados.

Answer (score 1):

Hay un evento llamado "fullscreenchange" que se lanza cuando se inicia o termina el modo de pantalla completa. Ademas usando `document.fullscreenElement` (con el prefijo apropiado) sabes si entras o sales de pantalla completa.

Pues por lo tanto, simplemente almacenar el valor de `style` en un atributo auxiliar (propietario) y restaurarlo al salir de pantalla completa. No lo he probado, pero es básicamente algo así:

```
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", onFullScreenChange);
document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", onFullScreenChange);
document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", onFullScreenChange);
document.addEventListener("msfullscreenchange", onFullScreenChange);

function onFullScreenChange() {
  var fullscreenElement = document.fullscreenElement || 
                          document.mozFullScreenElement || 
                          document.webkitFullscreenElement ||
                          document.msFullscreenElement;

  var elemento = $("#id_del_elemento");

  // verificas si entras o sales de pantalla completa
  if (fullscreenElement) { 
    // almacenas style en otra parte
    elemento.attr({ 'style-temporal' : elemento.attr('style') });
    elemento.removeAttr('style');
  } else {
    // restauras style al volver a modo normal
    elemento.attr({ 'style' : elemento.attr('style-temporal') });
    elemento.removeAttr('style-temporal');
  }
}
```

Comment: @md, se ve bueno, pero al hacer click  al botn de pantalla completa $(".full_pantalla").click(function (e) {......
como le paso el id que se va obteniendo de la base de datos al onFullScreenChange, aquí veo que el id es fijo: var elemento = $("#id_del_elemento");

Comment: @Danilo lo puse como ejemplo, debes usar el `$('#' + id_foto_full)` que venias usando. Dejame saber si necesitas algo mas.